# Implicit factories in UML sequence diagrams?

Tags: java, uml, factory, sequence-diagram

The following sequence diagram models the initialisation of a FTP server, which uses a couple of factories (`FtpServerFactory` and `ListenerFactory`) to create the required
objects. Unfortunately said interactions significantly increase the complexity of the diagram without adding any useful insight.

[image: original diagram]

I have drawn another sequence diagram omitting these factories, and in my opinion it looks much more clear.

[image: simplified diagram]

I wonder if it's possible to replace the `<<create>>` stereotype with (say) a `<<factory>>` stereotype to point out that the objects are instantiated by factories. 
Also, I'm a bit dubious about the reply messages, if it is necessary to show them or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the freedom to do so. Anything that serves communicating your thoughts is fine. You should in such cases add a comment (if you have no common document/glossary for it) to place a note on the diagram explaining the use of your `<<factory>>` stereotype.